# How to impliment email template to email in yii 1?

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my contoller called MessageController:

```
        $letter = $this->renderPartial('temp');
        $message=$letter;
        $mail = new YiiMailer('contact',array('message'=>$message,'name'=>'Message','description' => 'Message'));
        $mail->setSubject('Message');
        $mail->setFrom('anu.axmed@gmail.com', 'Company');
        $mail->setTo($_POST['useremail']);
```

Here `temp` is email template (`$letter = $this->renderPartial('temp');`).
But, it is not loading email template. `temp.php` is located in `message` view folder. How can I impliment email template to my email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you may need to set third parameter of `renderPartial()` to "true" `$this->renderPartial('temp', null, true);` so the rendering result will be returned not displayed.